# Scalaz error combining EitherT and OptionT

Tags: scala, scalaz

I´m doing an example using monad transformer EitherT of scalaZ with OptionT but I have a compilation error which I dont understand.

Here my example code

```
class EitherTMonadTransformer {

  case class Error(msg: String)

  case class User(username: String, email: String)

  def authenticate(token: String): Future[Error \/ String] = Future {
    \/.right("token")
  }

  def getUser(username: String): Future[Option[User]] = Future {
    Some(User("paul", "osmosis_paul@gmail.com"))
  }

  val userObj: Future[\/[Error, Nothing]] =
    (for {
      username <- EitherT(authenticate("secret1234"))
      user <- OptionT(getUser(username))
    } yield user.username).run


  @Test
  def eitherTAndOptionT(): Unit = {
    println(userObj)
  }
}
```

The compilation error says

```
Error:(32, 12) type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.OptionT[scala.concurrent.Future,String]
 required: scalaz.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,EitherTMonadTransformer.this.Error,?]
      user <- OptionT(getUser(username))
```

Any idea what´s wrong?

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, within a for expression, you cannot mix and match different monads as you wish. In this particular case you're trying to mix the `OptionT` monad with the `EitherT` one. Remember that monad transformers are themselves monad. The compiler, as soon as sees this line `username <- EitherT(authenticate("secret1234"))`, will infer `EitherT` as the monad used in the for expression and expect it for the rest of it. One possible solution is changing the type returned by your `getUser` method, e.g.:

```
def getUser(username: String): Future[Error \/ User] = Future {
  \/.right(User("paul", "osmosis_paul@gmail.com"))
}
```

Of course you will have to change the for expression as follows too:

```
val userObj: Future[\/[Error, String]] =
  (for {
    username <- EitherT(authenticate("secret1234"))
    user <- EitherT(getUser(username))
  } yield user.username).run
```

This way the types align and the compiler will happily accept them.

Comment: I understand, the for comprehension as all pipeline only admit one signature type thanks for the explanation.